# Real-time API calls between 8AM and 8PM only

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

Does anyone know if SFMC supports delayed sends for real-time API communications? Basically I want to know if SFMC can only send emails between 8AM and 8PM and any calls made outside this time frame are held until 8AM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Send Throttle](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_send_throttle.htm&type=5) would allow you to accomplish this.

> Configure Send Throttle when setting up an email send in Email Studio. Send Throttle sends emails during the hours you specify every day, starting the day you send the email, until all emails send.

[image: Send Throttling Triggered Send]

Comment: Thanks, I’m going to test this next week